# Office 365 SharePoint: Workflow to Custom App/Add-In

Tags: sharepoint, office365, add-in

I want to create a workflow in Office 365 SharePoint that opens a Custom App/Add-In as one of its Tasks.  Can I do this?  How?

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by "opens"? How does one open an addin?

Comment: By "open", I mean "appear to the User".  I want to create a workflow where a Task's Page is an App for SharePoint (now called SharePoint Add-In).